# Log4j slf4j not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-camel, slf4j

I am trying to get logging working in my Apache Camel project.
I have tried the following:

**VM args**
In eclipse I have added tried the following VM args:
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-/resources/log4j.properties
-Dlog4j.debug=true

**Properties file on class path**
I have doubled checked that log4j.properties is on the class path

My java looks like this:

```
Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelMain.class);
LOG.info("starting");
```

My pom contains the following:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-beanio</artifactId>
          <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>       
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
          </dependency>
```

Any ideas why the logging is not working?

**Update  / Solution**

I needed to add the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You have `log4j.debug=true` enabled, so what do you see on console?

Comment: You are supposed to have 3 logging dependencies : `log4j`, `slf4j` and `slf4j-log4j` (which links slf4j to log4j).

Answer (score 5):

Add following dependencies if you want to use `slf4j` over `log4j` and remove the dependencies for `org.apache.logging.log4j` and `commons-logging`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```